# I'm developing an App using Ionic Angular and PHP for the backend. I am returning this JSON string from PHP and I'm receiving it as it is in Angular

Tags: php, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

*I'm developing an App using Ionic Angular and PHP for the backend.
I am returning this JSON string from PHP and I'm receiving it as it is in Angular*

```
[
{
    "HistoryId":"440",
    "TotalPrice":"24",
    "aa":[{"orderid":"630","foodId":"1","quantity":"1","name":"Mixed Starter (Minimum For Two)","price":"9"},         {"orderid":"641","foodId":"3","quantity":"1","name":"Sesame chicken on toast","price":"5"},
          {"orderid":"662","foodId":"2","quantity":"2","name":"Sesame prawn on toast","price":"5"}]
},
{
    "HistoryId":"451",
    "TotalPrice":"24",
    "aa":[{"orderid":"650","foodId":"1","quantity":"1","name":"Mixed Starter (Minimum For Two) ","price":"9"},        {"orderid":"671","foodId":"3","quantity":"1","name":"Sesame chicken on toast","price":"5"},
          {"orderid":"682","foodId":"2","quantity":"2","name":"Sesame prawn on toast","price":"5"}]
}
]
```

*But when I try to show it
I receive this error:*

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in
a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression 
to specify unique keys. Repeater: oh in orderHistory,
Duplicate key: string:", Duplicate value: "
```

Comment: can you show us your iteration code ?

Comment: @Hamooz Can you post your angular code?

Comment: <ion-item " ng-repeat="oh in orderHistory " >
                <h2>{{oh.HistoryId}} </h2>
                <h3 style="color:green">Price: {{oh.TotalPrice }}</h3>
                <ion-card>
                    <ion-item   ng-repeat="o in oh.aa   "> @vineet

Comment: $scope.orderHistory= angular.toJson(response.data); @ashu jha

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="oh in orderHistory track by $index" > <h2>{{oh.HistoryId}} </h2> <h3 style="color:green">Price: {{oh.TotalPrice }}</h3> <ion-card> <ion-item ng-repeat="o in oh.aa ">
```

**AngularJS does not allow duplicates in a ng-repeat directive**

Comment: When I used it with $index it shows lots of iteration but without value only empty ionCards @vineet

Comment: they are not duplicated, that's why I put my JSON result

Comment: did you try this `<ion-item ng-repeat="o in oh.aa track by o.orderid">` ?

Comment: great @Hamooz. But it was difficult to guess whether you have deserialized json or not. :)